# How can I use an interface to normalize different structs?

Tags: go, struct, interface

I'm using Go to collect a variety of perfmon stats and would like to normalize them down to something like an E-A-V model, but am struggling to wrap my brain around how to accomplish this.

given these example structs:

```
type Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation struct {
    Name                    string
    C1TransitionsPersec     uint64
    C2TransitionsPersec     uint64
    C3TransitionsPersec     uint64
    PercentUserTime         uint64
    PercentInterruptTime    uint64
    PercentPrivilegedTime   uint64
    PercentC1Time           uint64
    PercentC2Time           uint64
    PercentC3Time           uint64
}
type Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkAdapter struct {
    Name                        string
    BytesSentPersec             uint64
    BytesReceivedPersec         uint64
    OffloadedConnections        uint64
    PacketsOutboundDiscarded    uint64
    PacketsOutboundErrors       uint64
    PacketsReceivedDiscarded    uint64
    PacketsReceivedErrors       uint64  
}
```

I'd like to normalize them to:

```
type Counter struct {
    counter_category        string
    counter_name            string
    counter_instance        string
    counter_value           uint64
}
```

Using `reflect` I've been able to come up with this:

```
func pivot(cpu_info *[]Counter, cpu Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation, category string) {
    e := reflect.ValueOf(&cpu).Ellem()
    for i := 0; i < e.NumField(); i++ {
        f_name := e.Type().Field(i).Name
        f_value := e.Field(i).Interface()
        if f_name != "Name" {
            c := Counter {
                counter_category: category,
                counter_name: f_name,
                counter_instance: cpu.Name,
                counter_value: f_value.(uint64),
            }
            *cpu_info = append(*cpu_info,c)
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have 17 counter categories that I'm collecting and I don't believe that writing 17 of these functions is the best idea (unless it is and I'm happy to be corrected).

I've gotten this far with a function that uses an interface, but I just don't know if I'm on the right path:

```
func pivot_counter(counter interface{}, counter_info *[]Counter) {
    var counter_category string
    switch t := counter.(type) {
    case []Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation:
        counter_category = "Processor"
        fmt.Printf("%T\r\n",t)
    case []Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkAdapter:
        counter_category = "Network Adapter"
        fmt.Printf("%T\r\n",t)
    default:
        counter_category = "Unknown"
        fmt.Printf("%T\r\n", t)
    }
}
```

But here is where I'm stuck because I'm still at a place where I'm going to need to create 17 different case statements with 17 different blocks of "pivot" logic within those cases. I know I'm doing something wrong. I'm essentially trying to write a function that will accept accept the struct/interface, determine type via type assertion, and then use that object to iterate the struct fields to pivot them out to a homogeneous format. Where do I go from where I currently find myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your interface:

```
type CounterMaker interface {
    MakeCounter() Counter
}
```

Now, for each type you have, make it support CounterMaker:

```
type Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation struct {
    ...
}

func (value Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation) MakeCounter() Counter {
    ... code to turn "value" into a counter ...
    return result
}
```

Repeat for the other types.

(The interface shown above is not necessarily the *right* one; pick the one that fits your situation.)

Now if you have some function that needs a Counter instance, you can make one, either before calling it, or inside it.  For instance:

```
func Increment(running *Counter, newstuff CounterMaker) {
    inc := CounterMaker.MakeCounter()
    // maybe double check that the running counter matches w/ "inc"
    running.counter_value += inc.counter_value
}
```

If you ran with this example—which, again, may not be the *right* way to do this—you could now pass a `Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation` value as the second argument to `Increment`, because it implements `MakeCounter` and therefore qualifies as a `CounterMaker`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I understand what you’re saying, I’m going to have to repeat the pivot logic for each of the 17 structs no matter which approach I take.

Comment: Maybe. It depends on what you're really trying to achieve, and what you really have. The example I used lets you put this logic in each implementation (each statistic type), but maybe there is a whole different approach. If not, the advantage of putting the logic in the code that defines the *type* is that you don't have to have a big type-switch, and you can add more types as long as they also implement the interface. That is, the interface operations give you type safety.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help and I'm not sure I'm quite explaining myself correctly. I'm attempting to convert both `Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkAdapter` and `Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation` (and 15 other structs) into a struct that looks like what I've defined in the `Counter` struct definition. I'm finding that I'm doing a LOT of code repetition, even though Go has a core tenet of "don't repeat yourself." So I'm still thinking that I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: Fundamentally, the issue is that you already have some entity types (A, B, C, through P or Q, or 1 through 17, or whatever) that have some sort of "shape". You're trying to transform each into some other thing (eg your E-A-V model) that has some other shape. That requires 17 different chunks of code, because you must select the right things from type A (or #1), the right things from type B (or #2), etc. The question is not how much code is required, but rather, how to arrange it for maintenance and the like.